# Contact server on significant location update in iOS

Tags: ios, service, location

I am using significant location update in my app. I have tested by writing the location updates to file. It is working perfectly fine. But how do I send the location update to the server?

Right now I am doing it this way, in `didUpdate` function, I am calling a function:

```
Login* login = [[Login alloc] init]; // Login is subclass of nsobject
[login sendLocUpdate:latLong];
```

In `sendLocUpdate`, I am using `NSUrlConnection` to send the location to server. This is not at all updating the server but it is executing the function that writes the location detail to file properly. Please help me out? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post code for sendLocUpdate?

Comment: NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
                NSURLConnection *connection;
                connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Login object the way it will persist all the time while the networking in a process. The "login" in your function is been destroying after the function run to the end. One possible way is to create it as a singleton instance (shared instance) and it will live all the time the app live.

Comment: But why? I did not get your answer.. I am allocating the object right.. Login* login = [[Login alloc] init]; Then why does it not work? How do I code for it? I am new to iOS. Sorry if this seems to be silly..

Comment: The networking code is run asynchronously and result returns later after you requested it. In this function you created login object, started the request, but when the function ends login object deallocated and nobody received the response. You should read about how to create Singleton instance and made Login class as singleton.

Comment: Ok.. I will try.. Thank you!